# Can we check if some values fall in a range if we have the sum of values?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a set of natural numbers.

Is there a way to check out whether all the numbers fall in a range, say from 10 to 20, by looking at their sum.

Or is their any such property of a range which helps us to identify it?

**Where I am coming from :**

I just had a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33970309/list-the-directories-whose-the-file-sizes-are-all-within-a-range) at Stack Overflow and I thought it would be nice just to look at the directory size to finalize that all the files inside
it are having a size in a particular range.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have two numbers x and y. If they are both in the range 10 to 20, then the sum is in the range 20 to 40. On the other hand, (x-100) + (y+100) has the same sum, and x-100, y+100 are both outside the range. You would need more information.

Comment: Is their any such property the identify a range?